# C adjacent stack addressing

Tags: c, stack

Do C compilers provide any guarantee on the placement of elements on the c stack such that accessing `a[3]` in `int a[2];` when a is proceeded by `int b[2];` for example:

```
int a[2];
int b[2];
a[3];
```

Provide access to b[1]; but via using "a"?

Comment: as a note: a[-2] seems to work in clang

Comment: Compilers might rearrange placement for alignment reasons.   There's no guarantee.

Comment: There's no guarantee, and the compiler or optimizer might nuke `a[-2]` at any time

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of local variables on the stack is entirely implementation depend, and can in fact change when more variables are added or removed or when compiler settings are changed.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
   
int main()
{
    int x;
    char y;
    double z;

    printf("&x=%p\n", (void *)&x);
    printf("&y=%p\n", (void *)&y);
    printf("&z=%p\n", (void *)&z);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled on gcc with `-O0`:

```
&x=0x7ffd15fa27ec
&y=0x7ffd15fa27eb
&z=0x7ffd15fa27e0
```

`z` is first, then `y`, then `x`:

When compiled with `-O3`:

```
&x=0x7ffd87f4a4c4
&y=0x7ffd87f4a4c3
&z=0x7ffd87f4a4c8
```

`y` is first, then `x`, then `z`:

So even on the same compiler it can vary.

Comment: I can understand why they would in the example you posted given the different types used, thus alignment optimizations, but in the aforementioned example if they where all the same type, would this still happen? i.e both a and b have the same type.

Comment: @thysultan Maybe, maybe not.  Either way, you shouldn't depend on it.